# Proper Syntax? Powershell error for missing parenthesis but only 6 parenthesis in command?

Tags: arrays, powershell, syntax, runtime-error, pipeline

the Powershell line:

```
 (Get-Content hist3.txt)  |  ForEach-Object { $_.split(" ",2)[0]}  |  ForEach-Object { $rgbArray = @($_)} | for( $i = 0; $i -le $rgbArray.length - 1; $i++ ) {$rgbArray[$i]}
```

The ERROR message:

> At line:1 char:114
>
> - ... " ",2)[0]} | ForEach-Object {$rgbArray = @($_)} | for( $i = 0; $i -le...
> - ~ Missing closing ')' in expression. At line:1 char:150
> - ... y = @($_)} | for( $i = 0; $i -le $rgbArray.length - 1; $i++ ) {$rgbAr...
> - ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression

The hist3.txt:

```
2 1388581  
3 1449812  
4 63829  
5 10477  
6 5878
7 6703  
8 105349
9 8639  
10 7270
```

1. So I am loading this text file  : `(Get-Content hist3.txt)`
2. I need to isolate the first word of each line: `ForEach-Object { $_.split(" ",2)[0]}`
3. save each first word into a single array: `ForEach-Object { $rgbArray = @($_)}`
4. then iterate over that array and access each element one by one : `for( $i = 0; $i -le $rgbArray.length - 1; $i++ ) {$rgbArray[$i]}`

my above code seems to be missing a parenthesis somehow. or maybe it doesn't recognize the $rgbArray later in the pipe?

can you tell me what information i am missing or need to read up on? How do i get this working?

the end goal is to actually load the elements into the array and then compare several of the elements to other elements in the same array. so i would be accessing multiple parts of the same array at once.

Very new to powershell so thank you for your help.

Comment: Statement (like `for`) can not be used in place of pipeline command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pipe anything into `for`. [About For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for) describes that it's a **language command** not a cmdlet.

Hard to guess your final aim. For start, try next code snippets in sequence to see what happens:

```
Get-Content 'hist3.txt'
```

then

```
Get-Content 'hist3.txt' | ForEach-Object { $_.split(" ",2)[0]}
```

and then

```
Get-Content 'hist3.txt' | ForEach-Object { $_.split(" ",2)[0]} | 
   ForEach-Object { 
        $rgbArray = @($_) 
        for( $i = 0; $i -le $rgbArray.length - 1; $i++ ) {$rgbArray[$i]}
   }
```

The latter is the same as next one-liner:

```
(Get-Content 'D:\PShell\Downloaded\hist3.txt.txt' )  |  ForEach-Object { $_.split(" ",2)[0]} |  ForEach-Object { $rgbArray = @($_); for( $i = 0; $i -le $rgbArray.length - 1; $i++ ) {$rgbArray[$i]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I selected this as the answer because it answered my original question very well. However, the array does not function as I anticipated. I posted a new question explaining the results:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667798/array-is-storing-each-character-of-text-file-separately-instead-of-whole-words-w

Answer (score 1):

```
#you can do simply that:
Import-Csv 'hist3.txt' -Delimiter ' ' -Header Col1, Col2 | select Col1


#or this
Get-Content 'hist3.txt' | %{ ($_ -split ' ')[0]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Import-Csv comment. I did not know that was possible. I think this will be very useful to me sometime soon.